# left join - trying to find missing records in 2nd table when there is still similar record fitting match condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have 2 tables

Table 1

- message type
- id

Table 2

- message type
- id

I want to find missing records in table 2 when:

1. Request is logged in Table 1 and 2 as:

Table 1 :
Message type: Request Send
ID: 1

Table 2 :
Message type: Request Received
ID: 1

2. Then response is send and it is logged only in Table 1.

Table 1 :
Message type: Response Send
ID: 1

Table 2 :

NOTHING

Now I do join to find missing responses in Table 2:

```
select t1.ID 
from Table1 as t1 
left join Table2 as t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID 
where t2.ID is null 
and t2.MessageType<>'Request Received'
```

Unfortunately I get 0 rows. I guess because there is t2 record with matching ID but it filer it out by MessageType condition. How I can solve this?

Comment: Is the database mysql or sql server?  You have both tagged.

Comment: move the `and` portion of your `where` clause into the `on` conditions to insure you are only trying to join against those records.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `not exists` clause should be sufficient:

```
select *
  from table1 t1
 where not exists (select null
                     from Table2 t2
                    where t2.id = t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem statement is not clear
Right the where is turning that into a regular join

```
select t1.ID 
from Table1 as t1 
left join Table2 as t2 
  on t1.ID = t2.ID 
 and t2.MessageType <> 'Request Received'
where t2.ID is null
```